# On very first time onMapLoaded() is not called in google maps android , onMapLoaded not working in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

For very first time `onMapLoaded()` is not called. My map is not showing for first time. But `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` called. But at second time map is loaded succesfully. Both `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` and `onMapLoaded()` called. I can not predict the issue. Please let me any idea to resolve my issue.

For map initialize

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

For onMapReady:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MapsActivity.this);            
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        setCustomInfoWindow();

    }
```

For onMapLoaded:

```
@Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            //mMap.snapshot(this);
            addMarkers();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this `mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);` in `onMapReady()`

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MapsActivity.this);            
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        setCustomInfoWindow();

    }
```

Try it.

Comment: I added that too. But still now first time is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

please don't confuse your self between `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` and `onMapLoaded()`. Here is a documentation you can  [refer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback)

Comment: Ok.. But map is not loaded for first time. In left bottom google icon alone is showing. But map is not loading. So What is the issue??

Comment: i had the similar issue with my debug.apk, but it worked fine with my release.apk